# Calculate certain ratios of "work", "low work", and "no work" over large date ranges

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I have the following algorithm to calculate certain ratios of "work", "low work" and "no work" over a set date range (`startDate`, `endDate`). The algorithm works fine, but when I increase the date range it obviously runs slower because it has to loop over every day of that range for every minute. Is there a way to improve the performance with a different kind of loop or for the where clause to find the current date within the `listWorkTime`.

```
private List<DateSharedWork> CalculateDateSharedWork(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, ICollection<WorkTime> listWorkTime)
        {

      List<DateSharedWork> listDateSharedWork = new List<DateSharedWork>();

      // +1 to include last day at full
      int range = endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days + 1;

      // start at startDate
      Parallel.For(0, range, i =>
      {

        DateTime currDate = startDate.AddDays(i);

        //set minute interval
        double everyNMinutes = 1.0;
        double minutesADay = 1440.0;

        // reset counter
        int work_counter = 0;
        int lowWork_counter = 0;
        int noWork_counter = 0;

        int l = (int)(minutesADay / everyNMinutes);

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {

          DateTime check15 = currDate.AddMinutes(j * everyNMinutes);

          // check if listWorkTime includes current date
          var foundTime = listWorkTime.Where(x => check15 >= x.FromDate && check15 <= x.ToDate).ToList();

          if (foundTime.Count(x => x.TimeRangeId == 1) > 0)
          {
            // found interval that is within work hours
            work_counter++;
            noWork_counter++;
          }
          else
          {
            if (foundTime.Count(x => x.TimeRangeId == 2) > 0)
            {
              // found intervall that is within low work hours
              lowWork_counter++;
              noWork_counter++;

            }
          }
        };

        double work = everyNMinutes / minutesADay * work_counter;
        double lowWork = everyNMinutes / minutesADay * lowWork_counter;
        double noWork = 1.0 - (everyNMinutes / minutesADay * noWork_counter);

        listDateSharedWork.Add(new DateSharedWork(currDate, work, lowWork, noWork));

      });

      listDateSharedWork.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.Date, y.Date));

      return listDateSharedWork;

    }
```

**Edit**

class definitions of DateSharedWork and WorkTime

```
public class DateSharedWork
  {

    public DateSharedWork(DateTime date, double? work = 0.0, double? lowWork = 0.0, double? noWork = 1.0)
    {
      this.Date = date;
      this.Work = work.Value;
      this.LowWork = lowWork.Value;
      this.NoWork = noWork.Value;
    }

    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public double Work { get; private set; }
    public double LowWork { get; private set; }
    public double NoWork { get; private set; }
  }

public class WorkTime
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FromDate{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? ToDate{ get; set; }
    public int? TimeRangeId{ get; set; }
  }
```

**Edit2**

starting from the `startDate` value as the first day and increasing on a minute scale for a the whole day, I get the ratios of *normal work* and *low work* for that day by the flag `TimeRangeId`,
`listWorkTime` contains information when a certain period was either work or low work, these periods can overlap and also beeing a duplicate, but *normal work* (`TimeRangeId == 1`) dominates

Comment: Could you please share with us the definitions of `WorkTime` and `DateSharedWork`?

Comment: Could you please confirm the following? You receive a start, an end datetime and a collection of timeframes. You want to calculate the intersection on a minute scale. You also want to distinguish *normal work* and *low work* based on a flag. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: that is correct, additional information on Edit2

Comment: Can please provide some sample data to be able to test / play with it locally?

Comment: Performance upgrading is often a careful balance between reasonable performance and reasonable code readability/maintainability. To that end: at what kind of date range (and with how many `WorkTime` entries) is the performance becoming unreasonable by your standards? How long does it then take? How long are you expecting it to take? If not a hard line, how much are you willing to sacrifice readability/maintainability for squeezed performance?

Comment: Is the "every N minutes" check a requirement, or is it an implementation detail to save on performance by not having to check every literal minute? If a solution was presented that calculates the answer down to the minute or even second and ignores any concept of time chunks, would this be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Would pre-emptive calculation and caching be a valid answer, or must this specifically be an on-the-fly calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few quick shots...

- Instead of having `DateTime check15` which leads to the assumption there may be some more `DateTime` structs laying around like check1...check15 you could just juse `currDate` which by the way should be renamed to `currentDate` because abbreviations will make the code harder to read. By using `currentDate` you could replace `(j * everyNMinutes` in `currDate.AddMinutes()`by just `1.0` or better `everyNMinutes`.
- `foundTime` as a name for a `List` isn't the best choice as a `List` implies more than one item. How about `foundTimes` ? But much more important is that for each minute the code iterates over `listWorkTime` at worst twice. If you only use `Count()` to check if there is **any** item found, then just use `Any()`. `Count()` will iterate over all items while `Any()` stops at the first found item.
- You should use a profiler to check if removing `ToList` after `Where()` will get more performance.
- the ideomatic way in c# to name variables is using `camelCase` casing instead of `snake_case`casing.
- instead of an `if` inside an `else` block you should use a `else if` instead.
- What bothers me more is what happens if there are items in `foundTimes` which would satisfy both conditions?

Implementing the mentioned changes without taking into account the last point looks like so

```
private List<DateSharedWork> CalculateDateSharedWork(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, ICollection<WorkTime> listWorkTime)
{

    List<DateSharedWork> listDateSharedWork = new List<DateSharedWork>();

    // +1 to include last day at full
    int range = endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days + 1;

    // start at startDate
    Parallel.For(0, range, i =>
    {

        DateTime currentDate = startDate.AddDays(i);

        //set minute interval
        double everyNMinutes = 1.0;
        double minutesADay = 1440.0;

        // reset counter
        int workCounter = 0;
        int lowWorkCounter = 0;
        int noWorkCounter = 0;

        int l = (int)(minutesADay / everyNMinutes);

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {

            currentDate = currentDate.AddMinutes(everyNMinutes);
            // check if listWorkTime includes current date
            var foundTimes = listWorkTime.Where(x => currentDate >= x.FromDate && currentDate <= x.ToDate).ToList();

            if (foundTimes.Any(x => x.TimeRangeId == 1))
            {
                // found interval that is within work hours
                workCounter++;
                noWorkCounter++;
            }
            else if (foundTimes.Any(x => x.TimeRangeId == 2))
            {
                // found intervall that is within low work hours
                lowWorkCounter++;
                noWorkCounter++;
            }

        };

        double work = everyNMinutes / minutesADay * workCounter;
        double lowWork = everyNMinutes / minutesADay * lowWorkCounter;
        double noWork = 1.0 - (everyNMinutes / minutesADay * noWorkCounter);

        listDateSharedWork.Add(new DateSharedWork(currentDate, work, lowWork, noWork));

    });

    listDateSharedWork.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.Date, y.Date));

    return listDateSharedWork;

}
```